# STR_REPLACE com Array

Tags: php

Como eu faço para trocar o espaço por %20 com valores que vem de um Array ?
Cheguei até aqui seguindo exemplos, mas continua dando erro:

```
foreach ($jsonArr['data'] as $row) {
    $nome[] = $row['artist']['name']; //artista
    $titulo[] = $row['title'];//nome da música
    $musica[] = $row['preview'];//audio de 30 segundos
    $album[] = $row['album']['cover_xl'];//foto do album 
    $titulo2 = str_replace(array(' ', '%20'), '', $titulo);
    echo $titulo2; }
```

Preciso disso para por na url de outra API

Answer (score 0):

Vou deixar aqui a solução, pode ajudar alguém.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($jsonArr['data'] as $row) {
    $nome[] = $row['artist']['name']; //artista
    $titulo[] = $row['title'];//nome da música
    $musica[] = $row['preview'];//audio de 30 segundos
    $album[] = $row['album']['cover_xl'];//foto do album 
    $titulo2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $titulo[$i]);
    echo $titulo2;
$i++;
```